# c# FileSystemWatcher and a Timer

Tags: c#, timer, filesystemwatcher

I have this strange, yet maybe very simple problem..

I have a `timer1` in my program that should start when I for example click a button. which it does..

However when I use the FileSystemWatch it does not trigger `timer1` for some reason I can't seem to figure out.. is there something special that prevents the timer from being triggered?

Starting time works here:

```
private void toolStripMenuItem2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Start();
    }
```

but here it does not..

```
        private void fsw_SS_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
    { 
        fsw_SS.EnableRaisingEvents = false;
        timer1.Start(); 
    }
```

Intellisense of Visual Studio does not show any problems, neither can i seem to find a solution out there.

timer settings are as followed:
Interval of `5000ms`, and a timer_tick event (setup properly).

My problem is either 1) the timer doesn't start or 2) it doesn't tick..

What is wrong here, as I said before using a manual button or tool strip menue item it starts fine...

Comment: Is the `Created` event actually being raised? Can you break into that block of code?

Comment: Yes the fsw_SS event is raised, as I i tried debugging with break points it goes through the enableraisingevents = false and timer1.start(). yet it does not start the timer.

Comment: ps. I just added the timer from the toolbox on the form

Comment: Okay, so simply using a `System.Timers.Timer` did the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that the events are raised on a background thread, which means that you are accessing the timer from the wrong thread. (You never said what `timer1` is, but I'm guessing it has thread affinity.)

Comment: As Raymond said, your are starting the timer in a different thread. Use your main form's Invoke method to start the timer.

Comment: oh, so you mean that since the FileSystemWachter is a different thread it technically creates another timer1, from the original one? Thanks, I'll give that a try

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's a good idea to use a WinForms timer in this particular scenario as @Raymond has pointed out you are dealing with different threads and may encounter unexpected behaviour. You should consider using [System.Threading.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.timer.aspx) instead.